# Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline script. I am using [the Bitbucket plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin) to build pull requests.

Within it, I am doing two checkouts. One is working and the other isn't.

This one is working:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
          branches: [[name: "origin/${branchName}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
          extensions: [], gitTool: 'jgit', submoduleCfg: [],
          userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: credentials,
                               name: 'origin',
                               url: repository]]])
```

Where `repository`, `credentials` and `branchName` are variables.

However, this one isn't working:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
          branches: [[name: "origin/pr/${pullRequestId}/merge"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
          extensions: [], gitTool: 'jgit', submoduleCfg: [],
          userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: credentials,
                               name: 'origin', refspec: '+refs/pull-requests/*:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*',
                               url: repository]]])
```

Where `repository`, `credentials` and `pullRequestId` are variables.

The error message is `Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job`.

Comment: Seems like a simple URL mistake problem. You should probably verify the `repository URL`, the name of the `branch` to checkout and the `refspec`.

Comment: How can I see if `"origin/pr/${pullRequestId}/merge"` is a valid branch? When I look over `branches`, did does not appear.

Comment: I don't think that a PR generates a specific branch. It just contains the info about the source repository and branch (e.g. `forkedRepo/master` or `forkedRepo/newFeature`). You can get all that info using [Bitbucket's pull requests API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests/%7Bpull_request_id%7D).

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same issue